# Binding ObjectDataSource Component to a DataSet

Tags: telerik-reporting

Telerik report designer using stored procedure return multiple data sets how to access all data sets. report shows only top dataset result

Please refer below link which is for binding dataset to report, which is using ASP.NET.

https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports/connecting-to-data/data-source-components/objectdatasource-component/bind-to-data-set

Is the same available for ASP.NET Core and Angular?

If so Please provide the full flow to create report, connect stored procedure, return dataset and configure to trdp report

Comment: I think you might have confused ChatGPT with StackOveflow.